# Have got in question

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use "Are you having got dinner at the moment?"
 (instead of "Are you having dinner at the moment?")
I want to know if it is possible to change **have** to **have got** in such questions

Comment: Why do you want to add *got*?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct.

To say:

> Are you having dinner at the moment

is equivalent to saying:

> Are you eating dinner at the moment

and inserting **got** makes no sense with either construction.

You might say:

> Have you got dinner ready (at the moment)?

meaning *Have you prepared dinner already?*

Or

> Are you getting dinner at the moment

which means **Are you getting dinner ready at the moment?**

But there's no other place for the verb *get* or *got*.